# wpf grid with frozen Column

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a Grid that contains User Controls, i'm using this Grid as a Matrix and i populate it with those User Controls.

I want to have the first column (ColumnDefinition) be frozen (from scrolling) of this Grid and so as the first Row (RowDefinition).

I will be so greatfull if you guys have any idea about this issue

This is what i want as a result

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question a bit?  Perhaps a bit of code showing what you've tried, and how it is failing you?

Comment: I populate the grid with c# code because i have parameters to pass into User controls. i will update my question and put a pict that may show you what i want as a result.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. The question couldn't be clearer IMO.

Answer (score 6):

After long hours of searching on google about this issue i found the solution ! also the answer of @voddy was helpful.

So the trick is to have a separed grid for the fixed Row (Header), same thing for the fixed Column and the Grid cells, so in the end we will be dealing with 3 Grid's witch every one of it have a ScrollViewer.

then we have to put them into a DockPannel and sychronize scrolling event using ScrollChanged Event and Horizontal and vertical Offsets .

Comment: I don't understand why your question has been closed : it is crystal clear to me since I have the same problem... Anyway, thanks for this answer !

Answer (score 2):

may be you can use a dockpanel for that purpose and have many grids positioned inside a dockpanel as you desire. It's difficult to suggest further as your requirement is not very clear.